# Subscription on child component not working in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I created a publication(on server) and subscription (on client) in MEteor + React application. My problem is, I can't receive the array returned by the publication. I used console.log in publication and it logs the subscription key and option. I check also documents before returning and it is correct. But in client, still cant get array of documents.

Here is my code for componentDidMount,

```
Meteor.subscribe("messages",{},{},function(err){
     console.log("err",err);
     console.log(Messages.find().fetch());
});
```

console.log here are not called.

Here is my code for publication,

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('messages', function (key,option) {
        console.log(key);
        return Messages.find(key,option);
    });
}
```

console.log here is working and also i checked the documents before returning and it is correct.

I used also react-router in my application.I add route for my parent component. The problem i have is in child component.

What is wrong with my code? or how to solve this problem?
I used msavin:mongol and still having 0 for the  count of documents.

Comment: From the docs: [_Meteor will queue incoming records until you declare the Mongo.Collection on the client with the matching collection name_](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe), have you done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Meteor Chef is promoting a nice folder structure. If you happen to use that, just to make sure your server side actions reach the server, meaning they are imported to the server. Just sharing a screen from one of my projects: 
[image]

register-api.js is further down imported in main.js in my server folder.

Secondly, what if you do your console.log(Messages.find().fetch()) outside the subscription. You put it into the callback function and should not really be there. What you normally do is to pass the result of Messages.find().fetch() to props in the component's container, so the result needs to be captured outside of your subscription.

Comment: I passed the result to props in the component's container but still no single document i get.